# How do I read XML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Alright, so I got this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<level>
    <tiles>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1111111111111111</row>
    </tiles>
</level>
```

and I got my XML reading code:

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
```

and

```
            function loadXML(){
                xmlDoc.load("levels/test.xml");
                xmlDoc.onload = readLevel();
            }
            function readLevel() {


                throw(xmlDoc);

                if(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles")[0].hasChildNodes()){
                    var rowNum = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles").getChildNodes();
                    level = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){
                        level[i] = [];
                        var tempStr = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles").childNodes[i].textContent;
                        for(var j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                            level[i][j] = parceInt(tempStr.charAt(j));
                        }

                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
                    blockArray[i] = []; // Create the second level for this index
                    for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {
                        var tempImg = new Image();
                        tempImg.src = "images/block" + level[i][j] + ".png";
                        blockArray[i][j] = new block(j * blockSize, i * blockSize, level[i][j], false, false, tempImg);
                        //throw('blockArray['+i+']'+j+'] = ' + level[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now why isn't this working? It constantly says `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles")[0]` is undefined and that `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles").length = 0`. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, there shouldn't be a space between `<` and `?`. How is `xmlDoc` being populated? And why do you [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#throw_Statement) an exception?

Comment: added space, nothing happened.

Comment: No, "shouldn't be a space" means you'll have to remove it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `XMLHttpRequest` and its `responseXML` property instead, which will work in all major browsers. Example:

```
function readLevel(xmlDoc) {
    alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);
    // Your existing code goes here
};

var createXmlHttpRequest = (function() {
    var factories = [
        function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    ];

    for (var i = 0, len = factories.length; i < len; ++i) {
        try {
            if ( factories[i]() ) return factories[i];
        } catch (e) {}
    }
})();

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        readLevel(xmlHttp.responseXML);
    }
};

xmlHttp.open("GET", "levels/test.xml", true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Sorry, but in this code it seems readLevel never gets called.

Comment: @CyanPrime: How do you mean? Do you mean by reading it or running it? `readLevel()` is called in the `onreadystatechange` handler. I've tried it and it works in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[According to SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMImplementation/createDocument), all the arguments are required in `createDocument`. Maybe the falsy values are tripping you up.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and got this: An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces" code: "14

Comment: Using this code: var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",'xml:lang',null);

Comment: @CyanPrime – Also see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocument).

Comment: Now using this var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', 'xml:lang',null); still not working

Comment: That namespace is reserved for (specific) element names starting with `<xml:...>`. You shouldn't need to specify a namespace at all.

Comment: Well, no matter what I do with that line it's all null anyway.