# How to do the CRUD for the XML by javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to ask how to use the javascript to do the CRUD for the XML file?

I searched the [How do I read XML in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776604/how-do-i-read-xml-in-javascript) for the read part. But can anyone give me some suggestions or reference to study this topic?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does "the XML file" live? on the client or server side?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify an XML file on a web server using just Javascript on the client side. You need some server side language/component (this can be server side Javascript as well such as node.js but that is a whole other topic).